# Uploading file to SkyDrive

Tags: microsoft-word, macbook, onedrive

I have a problem that has been annoying me for a while. I uploaded my C.V and shared my C.V on SkyDrive so that I can share it with prospective employers I have applied to online. However, when I click into my uploaded C.V, only the first page is able to be read. The rest (another 2 pages of resume) is not there. It is so frustrating as then I have to e-mail the employers again and send them the rest of my C.V

Does anyone know how to fix this??

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

- What kind of extension are you using on your cv try to convert it to pdf Everyone got pdf readers now a days

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a Word Document to SkyDrive and share the link with someone, you can select whether they need to sign in to view the document and whether they can edit it.

Regardless of the access level you provide the receiver can click the link they got via email and the document will open in the **Microsoft Word Web App**:

[image: 1]

As you can see above all the pages are visible and the document can be downloaded on demand.